# 3: Permission denied. at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2846)

Tags: java, permissions, sftp

We have a java code which connects to a destination server and places multiple files in the destination folder. But when it places the first file and comes back to place the second file it gives the following error.

INFO: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
INFO: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
3: Permission denied.
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2846)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:594)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:475)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:365)
        at TravelFTPUpload.main(TravelFTPUpload.java:103)
INFO: Disconnecting from 12.10.219.115 port 22
INFO: Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed

Java code snippet:

```
for (int j = 0; j < listFiles.length; j++) 
{
    fN = listFiles[j].getAbsolutePath();
    destFn = listFiles[j].getName();
    fileNameList.append(destFn+"<br />");

    // Ex:GS2-20141128
    sftpChannel.put(fN, destFn);

}
```

Can someone please help me with this error. 
Note: The code works fine while connecting to a different destination folder.

Comment: I am facing same problem. Did u get any solution?

Comment: I think you don't have sufficient permission to upload file into the "home" directory? You could also try `sftpChannel.put(fN,"./"  + destFn);` .....
"./" = currentDir

Comment: For me this was due to the length of or certain characters in the file name. I changed and reduced the length and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243278/permission-denied-using-jsch) and it was due an non existent folder. Did you check if the folder exists? Is it in the correct path?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to indicate the working directory in the channel

Use **channel.cd("/path_directory")**

```
ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
channel.cd("/path_directory");
```