# Permission denied using JSch

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I'm trying to retrieve some files from sftp server using JSch but I'm getting the following error.

```
3: Permission denied
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2846)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._realpath(ChannelSftp.java:2340)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.cd(ChannelSftp.java:342)
at com.company.common.sftp.impl.managedFile.moveFiles(managedFile.java:712)
```

Here is the code:

```
private List<String> moveFiles(String prefixFileName, String path) {
    Session session = getSession();
    Channel channel = connect(session);
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
    try {
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
        channelSftp.cd(_workingDir);
    ...
    }
    ...
    finally {
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    }
}

public Session getSession() {              
    Session session = null;
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    session = jsch.getSession(_user,_server,_port);
    session.setPassword(_password);
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", _strictHostKeyChecking);
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();
    return session;
 }

public static Channel connect(Session session) {
  Channel channel = null;
  channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
  channel.connect();
  return channel;
}
```

`_workingDir` is a property with the following value: `/user_files`.
Both folders (source and destination) are on a Windows server and all the privileges was granted to any user. But for some reason it doesn't let me change the current directory in the source (remote) server.

Any idea?

**UPDATE:** The Sftp server is freeFTPd and using a sftp client (like Filezilla) I can move files without problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably `/user_files` is an absolute path.

Try `./user_files` for a relative path to the user's home directory.

In Filezilla, it is `C:\user_files`  on the remote side ?

Comment: The folder `user_files` was not on the remote side. It was trying to access to a non existent folder. Thanks!

Comment: What if I try `/user_files` instead of `./user_files`?

Answer (score 1):

I have also meet the problem when using jsch in docker container, and fix the issue after chowning with the folder and starting sftp with root :

1. Start up the application with root ，not the other user, because it will work with the dir "/var/run" owned by root;
2. Because of (1), you should have a path owned by root to be the data path, you'd better give full privileges to the path:chmod 777 /yourpath;
3. Mention: you should mkdir when logining the sftp server with "sftp -P 22 admin@127.0.0.1", not to do it in data path, because the path will owned by root or other system user, but not the user in your sftp system, so that you can not upload files(because permission denied);
4. After changing all of above, I can finally upload and download files on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue was encountered by me and verifying the followings fixed my issue:

1. Path of the file we are trying to retrieve doesn't exist. So, please make sure that file actually exists under the directory that your application is accessing to retrieve the file.
2. Make sure SFTP user that you are using in the application to make the connection is configured and active in SFTP.
3. If above both points are valid in your scenario then try after rebooting the SFTP service.

Answer (score -1):

The same happened to me. And it was solved by adding only the route on the server. example

Example

```
ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
channel.cd("/path_directory");
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's say your connecting to C:/user_files/
Trying to read/copy all the files

Ensure there is no sub folder exists on the C:/user_files/
if folder exists a different approach needs to be followed using folder reading.
Hope this helps...